# How to plot function with 2 variables and involving factorials in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, equation

I could not find a viable solution to this problem (and I am a beginner in R).

I have an equation as shown below

[image]

where *n* and *K* are constants. *a* and *b* are the variables.

> How do I generate a 2-dimensional plot for the above in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly will this plot look like? Are you fixing `n` and `K` at some known value? What goes on the two axes?

Comment: Don't we need to solve the equation first? Then we can create randomized observations for one variable and calculate the others.

Comment: @MrFlick , I want to find the behavior of this plot (I don't know how it will look ; I'm hoping that it'll be some sort of a curve with **a** and **b** as the axes - am I assuming this wrong? Perhaps, its a 3-d plot?). *n* and *K* values vary depending on the model specifications, but for a given model *n* and *K* are fixed

Comment: @zyurnaidi, I tried solving the equation (supposing certain conditions like **a** tends to infinity - so that I could use Stirling's approximation), but it failed. The equation has factorial, and I didn't know how to proceed

Comment: @MrFlick, basically, given *n* and *K* values, I want to find the values of **a** and **b** satisfying that equation. I thought plotting would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
factorialfunction <-function(a,b, n, K){
K*(b^a)*((2+b)^(n+a))
}


Klist = c(1,5,10,50,100,200)
nlist = c(1,5,10,50,100,200)
#note that the n and K values are recycled, make them whatever you wish, they are constants, 
#while a and b take on any values, here 100 values between zero and one
res <- mapply(factorialfunction,a = seq(.01,1,by=.01),
b=seq(.01,1,by=.01), n = rep(nlist,each = 100), K=rep(Klist, each=100))

#Then you can plot this six times.

#allow six plots on the panel if you want
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
#loop through different plots
for (i in 1:6)
plot(1:100,res[1:100 + (i-1)*100])
```

Note In this code I chose a and b to be between zero and one, I am not familiar with this function but It looks like some type of Beta.

You can generate more than 6 plots by changing `klist` and `nlist` and your `par` and `for` loop parameters.

Here is what you get, note this code is customizable to produce the plots for the values of n, K, a, and b that you want. [image]

Comment: Aren't you using just the right hand side of the equation? What about (a-1)!*(1+b)^(n+2a) ?

Comment: **a** and **b** values range from 0 to infinity [>0]